# ASP.NET login refers on Server IIS to the Home, Local IIS works

Tags: asp.net, iis

Although my tool works on my own machine (ASP.NET 4.5) It begins this:

```
http://localhost/KnownErrorDatabase/login?ReturnUrl=%2fKnownErrorDatabase%2fHome&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
```

And i did an exact copy of it from exporting it from the iis into an ZIP File, and importing it on the server (NOTE: I did check the authentification mode (Everythings Checked!)
Although my local IIS Starts with the Login, the Server not. The Page works and, on my local IIS, other PC's in the intranet can login etc. But now the Error: If i click the login button (that refers to the page) i get redirected to the Homepage of the WebApp... Does anybody know whats the matter at it? IIS is on both machines on version 7.5
Greetings Ethnor

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of a setting in IIS.  Your default page is probably set to your home page instead of your login page.  Otherwise, your IIS server is set to allow Anonymous users.  So, no authentication/login is happening.  Check the authentication settings in IIS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, At the local IIS i did check the same authentification settings as on the server (anonym, Identity Change and Forms Authentification. So i did on the server. Did not change the error at all :(

Comment: Is your app (folder) configured to be an application?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164124(v=vs.90).aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cek8kw6e(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<location path="login.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Adding this to my web.config fixed the problem